# Winternitz hash based signature signing and verification

Tags: hash, signature, hash-signature

In Winternitz hash based signature

There are two functions
$f: \{0,1\}^n \to \{0,1 \}^n$, a one way function
and $g: \{0,1\}^* \to \{0,1 \}^n$, cryptographic hash function

Key Generation steps

- First $w$ is selected, where $w$ is number of bits signed simultaneously.
- The $t_1$ and $t_2$ is calculated as $t_1 = \lceil \frac{n}{w}\rceil$ and $t_2 = \lceil \frac{\lfloor log_2t_1\rfloor +1+w}{w}\rceil$, $t = t_1 + t_2$
- Signature Key (Private key) is then chosen at random $X = (x_{t-1}, ..,x_0)\in \{0,1 \}^{n, t}$
- Verification key (public key) $Y$ is calculated by applying $f$ function $2^{w} - 1$ times on each bit of $x_i$

Signing steps

- Compute digest of message $d = g(M)$
- Prepend minimum number of zero's to make length of $d$ divisible by $w$

My questions are

How is signature $\sigma$ computed? I am unable to understand from [Post Quantum cryptography](https://www.e-reading.club/bookreader.php/135832/Post_Quantum_Cryptography.pdf). Explanation with example would be helpful.

Why there is two functions $f$ and $g$, is there can be only one hashing function. What is the role of function $f$?

https://csrc.nist.gov/csrc/media/events/workshop-on-cryptography-for-emerging-technologies/documents/mcgrew-sigs.pdf

https://www.e-reading.club/bookreader.php/135832/Post_Quantum_Cryptography.pdf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How is signature $\sigma$ computed?

Well, you left a few steps out of your signing steps:

> Signing steps
>
> - Compute digest of message $d = g(M)$
> - Prepend minimum number of zero's to make length of $d$ divisible by $w$

(Note: in practice, the length of $d$ is typically already divisible by $w$, and so this step usually doesn't do anything; in any case, $d$ will be $t_1$ digits long after this step)

- Generate an "inverse checksum" of $d$; that is, treat $d$ as $t_1$ digits of length $w$ each $d_0, d_1, ..., d_{t_1 - 1}$, compute $k - \Sigma\  d_i$ for some constant $k \ge t_1 (w-1)$, and express that as the $t_2$ digits $d_{t_1}, d_{t_1 + 1 }, ..., d_{t_1 + t_2 -1}$
- For each $d_i$, take $x_i$ and apply $f$ to it $d_i$ times
- The result of these operations on the $t_1 + t_2$ digits are concatenated; that's your signature

You asked for an example, here's a toy one; let us assume that $w=2$ and $n = 4$.  Then:

- We have $t_1 = 2$ and $t_2 = 2$
- We compute $g(M)$ as `0111`, which is $\{ 1, 3 \}$ as expressed as $w$-bit digits
- We don't need to prepend any zeros, the length of $d$ is already a multiple of $w$
- We generate our inverse checksum; we have $d_0 = 1$ and $d_1 = 3$; we'll use the minimal $k = 6$, and so we have $k - \Sigma \ d_i = 2$, which we'll encode as $d_2 = 0$ and $d_3 = 2$
- We compute the Winternitz chain for $d_0$; $d_0 = 1$, and so this is $f(x_0)$; that's the first 2 bits of the signature.
- We compute the Winternitz chain for $d_1$; $d_1 = 3$, and so this is $f(f(f(x_1)))$; that's the second 2 bits of the signature.
- We compute the Winternitz chain for $d_2$; $d_2 = 0$, and so this is $x_2$ (that is, for digits of 0, we give out the private key value); that's the third 2 bits of the signature.
- We compute the Winternitz chain for $d_3$; $d_3 = 2$, and so this is $f(f(x_3))$; that's the last 2 bits of the signature.

> Why there is two functions $f$ and $g$, is there can be only one hashing function. What is the role of function $f$?

They, of course, perform different roles; $g$ hashes an arbitrary message down to $n$ bits; while $f$ is a one-way function that is used within the Winternitz chain itself.  They are usually (but not always) based on the same hash function; however how the hash function is used is typically optimized for each role separately.

---

Of course, in practice, we do a few refinements of the above scheme:

- We actually use a different $f$ function for every iteration, and for every digit; that's to avoid multi-target attacks
- Our public key really isn't $(t_1 + t_2)n$ bits long; typically, there's a final step that combines them into a single $n$ bit value.

Knowledge of these refinements is not necessary to understand Winternitz signatures; however you ought to be aware of them if you dig into a real usage.

Comment: x = 
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0&1 \\
1&0&1&1 \\
1&0&1&0
\end{bmatrix}
 y = 
\begin{bmatrix}
0&0&1&0\\
1&1&1&0 \\
0&1&0&1 \\
\end{bmatrix}

$\sigma = (f(x_3),x_2, f(x_1), f^3(x_0)) = $
 
\begin{bmatrix}
0&0&1&1 \\
0&0&0&1 \\
0&0&0&1 \\
\end{bmatrix}

where $f(x) = x + 1 \; mod \; 8 $ When i calculate $f^3(x_0) = f(f(f(x_0)$ it comes $001$, but here in the this example it comes $110$

Comment: Note that x is signature key and y is verification key. It is example from following book page :$39$ example : $3$https://www.e-reading.club/bookreader.php/135832/Post_Quantum_Cryptography.pdf

Comment: The example in the book is wrong; the typo'ed the last column of the $\sigma$ matrix.  Yes, the authors are well respected; typos happen...

Comment: Is this possible that there is only hash function. That is applied $2^{w-1}$ times. Is there cases where this modified Winternitz scheme is used.

Comment: 'Is this possible that there is only hash function'; I have no idea what you are asking...

Answer (score 2):

Let's examine a much simpler system, which has the same needs but none of the complicated key generation: the **Lamport–Diffie one-time signature** scheme.

A **public key** is a set $2n$ of $n$-bit strings $Y_{i,b}$, for $b \in \{0,1\}$ and $0 \leq i < n$.

A **signature** under a public key on a message $M$ is a set of $n$-bit strings $X_i$, such that if the $i^\mathit{th}$ bit of the string $g(M) = b_0 b_1 b_2 \dots b_{n-1}$ is $b_i$, then $f(X_i) = Y_{i,b_i}$.

To generate a public key, the signer picks $2n$ $n$-bit strings $X_{i,b}$ uniformly at random as the **private key**, and reveals $Y_{i,b} = f(X_{i,b})$.  To sign a message, the signer simply reveals $X_i = X_{i,b_i}$, where $b_i$ is again the $i^\mathit{th}$ bit of $g(M)$.

Since $f$ is one-way and the $X_{i,b}$ were chosen uniformly at random, nobody can guess $X_{i,b}$ from $Y_{i,b}$.

The function $g$ is necessary to compress a message into a small representative, and consequently either it must be collision-resistant or it must be randomized.

Of course, once you have revealed $X_i = X_{b_i,i}$, everyone knows what it was, so you can't use this to sign another message because now the cat's out of the bag—at least, *some* of the cat is out of the bag.

A public key is $2n$ bits in this system, and a signature is $n^2$ bits.  (We could have different sizes for the images of $f$ and $g$, if you like, making it $2n$ *versus*, say, $n\cdot m$.)  The Winternitz signature scheme saves some space in signatures at the cost of some time in key generation: in the 2-bit case, a signature on a message $M$ is a set of $n/2$ strings $X_i$ such that $$Y_{2i,b_{2i} b_{2i+1}} = f^{2b_{2i} + b_{2i+1}}(X_i);$$ that is, we break the message into two-bit chunks, and use the bit to select how many iterations of $f$ to apply to verify the newly revealed secret.